# Issue with lightning app when using lightning out

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

Hi guys I have made a nodejs app and want to expose my lightning app in it.

The component seems to render but some functionality does not work in the dev console I am getting these errors:

Access to Font at 'https://quintessentially--devamir.lightning.force.com/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff2' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

localhost/:1 Access to Font at 'https://quintessentially--devamir.lightning.force.com/_slds/fonts/v2.3.0/SalesforceSans-Regular.woff' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://quintessentially--devamir.lightning.force.com/resource/1498143923000/Lightning_Library/lib/jquery-2.2.4.min.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I am using jquery to do some interactions like hide/show sections these things are not working but the main functionality like saving does.

Comment: Hi, I've come across a similar issue. Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Same problem here.

Comment: Hi, did you resolve it ? I am facing the same issue!